# SendGrid/LiveRez/UnLayer.... encountering formatting issues/broken images

Tags: html-table, crm

Soooooo background. I do not have a coding/HTML background. I'm a front desk rep with a property management company and I'm trying to update our email templates. We use LiveRez for CRM/email template *hosting*, then it gets processed through SendGrid to go to the guest, in a way that will track which links are clicked. I started using UnLayer to work on our templates from the ground up, since I can copy/paste the code directly into the CRM system for each template. In earlier tests to myself, it seemed to work fine, aside from a LiveRez-end macro that I do not have the ability to alter formatting incorrectly.

I thought that it might be the table itself, so I edited the code to remove the surrounding table from the macro (please keep in mind i have no idea what i'm doing), and it is still generating a broken table with text running vertical instead of laid out clearly.

In addition, while I was finalizing my original updates (before removing the table), I transferred all images from the UnLayer server to our local server for hosting. Now when sending the test email to myself, those images are broken.

This is what the original (with certain information/identifying images redacted):

https://codepen.io/codespren/pen/poQbePP

```
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="font-family:'Rubik',sans-serif;" width="100%">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left" style="overflow-wrap:break-word;word-break:break-word;padding:10px;font-family:'Rubik',sans-serif;">
                        <div style="font-size: 14px; line-height: 140%; text-align: left; word-wrap: break-word;">
                        <p style="line-height: 140%; text-align: center;"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="5"  bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <tr class="green_tr">
        <td nowrap>Reservation #</td>
        <td><strong>9876543</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="green_tr">
        <td  nowrap>Process Status:</td>
        <td width="100%"><strong>APPROVED</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="green_tr">
        <td nowrap>Date Processed:</td>
        <td><strong>6/5/2023</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="green_tr">
        <td>Date Updated:</td>
        <td><strong>6/8/2023 11:10:00 AM</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="green_tr">
        <td nowrap>Balance Due Date: </td>
        <td nowrap  colspan="4"><strong>12/20/2023</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="grey_tr">
        <td nowrap><strong>Adults</strong></td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="grey_tr">
        <td nowrap><strong>Children (Under 12)</strong></td>
        <td width="100%">2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="5" bgcolor="ffffff">
    <tr class="grey_tr" style="height:35px;">
        <td><strong>Options</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Price $</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Quantity</strong></td>
        <td align="right"><strong>Totals</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="rezPricing">
        <td nowrap><strong>*Lorem Ipsum 123</strong></td>
        <td valign="top">
            <div id="showpricingcontainer">
                <div id="showdaysContainer"><div class="showdays">Average Nightly Rate $123.00</div></div>
                <div id="showmonthweekContainer"></div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td align="right">$123456</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="4" bgcolor=#ffffff style="padding-top:10;"><strong style="color:#000000;">Alaska Outfitterz:</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="green_tr">
        <td>Alaska Outfitterz </td>
        <td>
$0.00
            Flat Rate
            
        </td>
        <td>
            1
        </td>
        <td align="right">$0.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr bgcolor="#ffffff">
        <td nowrap style="padding-top:10;"><strong style="color:#000000">Fees and Totals</strong></td>
        <td> </td>
        <td> </td>
        <td align="right"> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="green_tr">
        <td>Service Charge</td>
        <td>
            
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td align="right">$90.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="green_tr">
        <td>Oopsies Waiver </td>
        <td>
            
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td align="right">$25.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="grey_tr">
        <td colspan="2"> </td>
        <td><strong>SubTotal:</strong></td>
        <td align="right">$12345.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"> </td>
        <td nowrap bgcolor="#D8D8AF"><strong>Sales Tax</strong></td>
        <td align="right">$10.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="green_tr">
        <td> </td>
        <td> </td>
        <td nowrap bgcolor="#D8D8AF"><strong>Non-Taxed Items</strong></td>
        <td align="right">$115.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan=2 width="100%"> </td>
        <td bgcolor=#F1F4F7><strong>Total</strong></td>
        <td align=right>idk some math stuff ending in an 8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#EDEDDC">Deposit is not available (full balance amount is required)</td>
        <td bgcolor="#77773C" nowrap><strong style="color:#ffffff;">Reservation Hold Payment</strong></td>
        <td align="right">$0.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4" class="grey_tr"><br><strong style="font-size:14px;">Payments</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="grey_tr">
        <td colspan="4" align="right">
            <table width="100%" cellpadding=3 cellspacing=1 border=0>
                <tr class="grey_tr">
                    <td valign="top">
                        <strong>Billing:</strong><br>
                        john cena<br>
                        123 banana court<br>
                        Las Vegas, NV, idk the zip<br>
                    </td>
                    <td valign="top">
                        <strong>Credit Card: </strong><br>
                        V - ************1009<br>
                    </td>
                   <td align="right">
                        <strong>
                            Payment Amount:<br>
                        </strong>
                    </td>
                   <td align="right">
                        <strong>
                        <br>in full
                        </strong>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <strong>
                            APPROVED: 6/5/2023 3:09:06 PM
                        </strong>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="grey_tr">
                    <td colspan="4" height="2"><td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="grey_tr">
        <td colspan="2" align="right" height="25"></td>
        <td align="right"><strong>Payment Totals</strong></td>
        <td align="right"><strong>$in full</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="grey_tr">
        <td colspan="2"> </td>
        <td align="right" style="padding:15;"><strong style="font-size:15px;">Balance Due</strong></td>
        <td align="right">$0.00</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="3"  bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <tr>
        <td class="grey_tr"><br><b>Guest Information</b></td>
        <td class="grey_tr"><br><b>Billing Information</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top">
            <table width=250 cellpadding=3 cellspacing=1 border=0>
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top" nowrap>
                        john cena
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        123 banana court<br>Las Vegas, NV, idk the zip<br>US
                    </td>
                </tr>
                    <tr><td>Ph: pretend theres numbers here my dudes</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Cell Ph: pretend here too</td></tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>johncena@wwe.net</td>
                    </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td valign="top">
            <table width=250 cellpadding=3 cellspacing=1 border=0>
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top" nowrap>john cena</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>123 banana court<br />Las Vegas, NV, idk the zip<br />US</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Ph: buUuUuuUullllshitteeeee</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</p>
                        </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

This is the snip of code that's generated from the macro - I don't have any control over this. The full code at the link is ALMOST what it should look like complete, but the formatting on the far right is where the problem is.

I thought that it might be the table itself, so I edited the code to remove the surrounding table from the macro (please keep in mind i have no idea what i'm doing), and it is still generating a broken table with text running vertical instead of laid out clearly. I used a code editor to visualize it a little better, and I'm not missing any code ends (what do you call them?). The invoice macro is also something managed by LiveRez, and I cannot access the code that is generated from it.

In addition, while I was finalizing my original updates (before removing the table), I transferred all images from the UnLayer server to our local server for hosting. Now when sending the test email to myself, those images are broken. Both times, SendGrid essentially made a copy of those images (I'm talking like, the email banner, a map image, and the social media icons at the bottom), and the URL source is updated for those images to something crazy-long.

I'm **HOPING** that my template will remain stable enough to be able to implement with the few changes needed between CRM content (arrival info, invoicing, late arrival, welcome, survey info, etc). I need the images to not be replaced by SendGrid content.

**Edit:**a friend from my office stopped by and took a look at the code, and we were able to determine there was something up with the `<td>` columns on the far right side, but when trying to edit this part:

```
        <td colspan=2 width="100%"> </td>
        <td bgcolor=#F1F4F7><strong>Total</strong></td>>
```

We adjusted some of the colspan values across this part of the code, and could not get the final Total column to work. As a note, while the code below just has gibberish, this problem duplicates regardless of the number of characters.